# How to correctly display a String resource with a variable

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I got a warning message that says:

> [I18N] Hardcoded string `"Something : " + someVariable`, should use @string resource.

> The line of code is: `mTextView.setText("Something : " + someVariable);`

I usually resolve this problem by extracting it to a string resource like :

> `mTextView.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.mSomething) + someVariable);`

This obviously cannot be used when you have a variables which you want to display. So what is the correct way to display a String resource with a variable without getting a warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have arguments in your string resource. For your example, have:

```
<string name="mSomething">Something: %s</string>
```

`%s` is wildcard for a string argument.

Then, in your fragment / activity, do:

```
String text = getString(R.string.mSomething, someVariable.toString())
```

Then you can use this text further as needed. You can also call the `getString()` function on `context` if you are not in fragment / activity.

Comment: The wildcard %s stands for the same in C as it stands in Android Studio? For example %d expects a number?

Comment: Sorry, I correct myself, there's wildcard for float - `%f`, `%d` is for non-decimal. They are quite the same as in C, that you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Better solution is to use concat function instead '+' operator to avoid this warning message, so the code should be like:`mTextView.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.mSomething).concat(someVariable);`

Comment: Thanks, good to know, this works as well.